# OpenCV: VideoCapture not working with DSHOW backend

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, directshow

I built OpenCV (with mingw 4.9.2 @ Win7Prof64) with
CMake switches for WITH_FFMPEG and WITH_DSHOW turned on.
When I access a movie file with `VideoCapture (fileName)` works fine (it uses ffmpeg backend then).

But `VideoCapture (fileName, cv::CAP_DSHOW)` doesn't work
(`isOpened()` returns false).

What is missing/ what do I do wrong?
Are there any kind of dshow libs/ dlls needed?

Comment: what kind of direct show device do you try to access?

Answer (score 0):

As to my [duplicate in opencv forum](http://answers.opencv.org/question/159416/videocapture-not-working-with-dshow-backend/) ... cv::CAP_DSHOW is not implemented for files.